# Is there a Multithread version of TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer?

Tags: delphi

With the actual implementation of `TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer`, you must do in the **same Thread** `MyMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer.beginRead` and `MyMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer.endRead`

However me I need to call `MyMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer.beginRead` in one thread and call `MyMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer.endRead` in another thread (this because I use winapi IO completion block)

Is there any way ?

Comment: Surely you'd be better using a SRW lock

Comment: hmm interesting didn't know about it! would be interesting to know why emb didn't use it to implement their TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer

Comment: Because they want to be cross platform and the Emba class existed before the windows object. The SRW lock is surely more efficient and less likely to be defective. Emba don't have a great record writing correct synchronisation primitives.

Comment: Of course I've no reason to suspect that the SRW lock won't have the same thread affinity requirements

Comment: @loki I assume you mean "IO completion ports"? But this raises some confusion. Is there a reason you need to lock and begin reading before IO _completes_? Is there a point to using completion ports at all in this case? What you're proposing sounds like a recipe for deadlock disaster.

Comment: @CraigYoung: it's because the io completion is inside IIS response (i send response in async) and if the user have a low connection, it's can be very long to wait. i need to write lock the store file to be sure no one is anymore reading on it before to "swap" it

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: in android/iOs I just check and  TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer is writen like .. TMonitor :) so no really any cross platform ;)